# Android WebView client shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method is not getting called for redirect urls

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to intercept the code from the redirect I get from Instagram Authentication. I'm using the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() to stop the page from loading, but the WebView goes ahead and loads it anyway. Here is my code

```
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            String url = view.getUrl();
            if (url.startsWith("https://someurl.com")){
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the server is sending an HTTP 3xx result? Or is the Web page at `https://someurl.com` doing its own quasi-redirection via JavaScript or something?

Comment: Yes its loading that url, I have just realised that I was getting the url from the WebView instead of retrieving it from the WebResourceRequest, posting an answer in a few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I was using the WebView URL instead of the URL from the WebResourceRequest, The following code `String url = view.getUrl();` should look like this `String url = String.valueOf(request.getUrl();` And the whole method will look like so:

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

        String url = String.valueOf(request.getUrl();
        if (url.startsWith("https://someurl.com")){
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```